# Programming in C

Tags: c

Sorry if question sounds stupid to you or it is too easy but i really do not know what im missing here (or im just stupid and dont understand the errors i am getting).

Im still starting to learn about C programming.

So what im trying to do is to find out how many times will "Red" print on the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i;

    for(i=4;i<15,i=i+3); { printf(“Blue\n”);
                           printf(“Red\n”);
                           printf(“White\n”);
                         }
    return 0;
}
```

The errors i am getting are:
Error expected ';' before ')' token
Error stray '\223' in program 
Error stray '\' in program

I was trying to find examples on the internet but nothing appears

Every help is appreciated. After all I'm learning.

Comment: In `for(i=4;i<15,i=i+3);` remove last `;` symbol. And also `,` should replace with `;`.

Comment: Take a look on the for-loops or just google it and compare it to your code

Comment: Please [edit] your post and update the title to something meaningful that describes the problem you're trying to solve or question you're asking. We can see your question is about C due to the tag you added and the code you posted, and the fact that you're posting code here makes it clear that it's *programming*, which makes your current title useless. It should be clear enough about what you're asking to be useful to future readers who are searching the site looking for a solution to their problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also, you can't use smart quotes (the ones that curl) in code. Stop writing your code in a word processor and use a text editor instead, and use plain double quotes "like these" instead.

Comment: Change the open/close quotation marks in the `printf` statements to the plain quote character `"`.

Comment: HAHAHAH hey @Kalana you just saved me and i had 100/100 points on the test! Thanks a lot. I used google translate to fast translate whole page of conversation https://prnt.sc/sebp00  some parts are translated badly. Professor you made a mistake* Surrender=submit* (marks it as done)

Answer (score 2):

Your for statement has a comma where it should have a semicolon.  The "i<15" part should be followed by a comma.

(Also, since your entire for statement has a semicolon immediately after it, before the block, Red will only be printed once.)

Comment: Also OP used some fancy quote symbols instead of regular quotes.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The question is about how many times "Red" will be outputted. So what is written in the answer does not make sense relative to the question.:) The correct answer is never.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It's within the brackets though. And of course, after removing the syntax errors. So, how is the correct answer "never"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow *"answer is never"* Only if you don't count error messages. :P

Comment: Its actually my professor that made this mistake when giving us exercises , thats why I was wondering :D

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Only if you don't believe in Quantum Mechanics :P

Comment: @shutupnoobs you are new here so I don't want to be harsh but using SO to do your homework is not really what it's for.  I know I answered your question but frankly, you can learn how to figure this out for yourself.   It just requires paying close attention to the exact syntax of the statement and the error message you get.  You have to verify that every element of the for-statement follows what you've learned about them.  I know it's tedious but you'll find this stuff much easier if you take the time and have the patience to do it.  Good luck.

Comment: I realized that it's like im stuck with 20 professors in the same room that get mad at every thing i ask. Sorry that i've chosen wrong path and came to SO. For sure not place for me. Anyways thanks for your help @Joe have a great day sir

Comment: @shutupnoobs SO is one of best place for all developers. In the begging lot of us ask question likes you did here. After visiting and studying from this site frequently you will understand, why SO will exist in this world. Thank you :)